# Form Design Issue with Checkbox, limitting checked area

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple form having a checkbox. The code I am using is

```
 <label>
    <span>Questions:
       <div class="childWindow">  
         <input class="checkedInput" id="defAsked" name="defAsked" type="checkbox" checked/>
    </span> 
 </label>
    <span>Send frequently asked questions</span>
       </div>                 

 <label>      
  <textarea rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="Please ask if you have any questions" name="questions" id="questions" ></textarea>
</label>
```

I would like to limit the checkbox's effective checked area to limit to box only, currently if I am clicking on the `text:Send frequently asked questions`, checkbox gets toggled. I am gonna give a link to this text, so would not want it to toggle when clicked on the link

Comment: So don't put the text inside of the `label`.

Comment: according to suggestions, i've edited a code, which does not work.

Comment: I've just edited the code to make the tags aligned correctly ***but*** as you can see, looks like it's invalid. The `<span>` (before `Questions:`) have its closing tag inside the `<div class="childWindow">`, the `<div class="childWindow">` has its openning tag inside the `<span>`... terrible HTML code.

Comment: what is invalid? code? what is wrong?

Comment: @oh_dear_i_love_coding scan your HTML code and see where are the openning and closing tags of your `span`? and where are the openning and closing tags of your `div`? (I mean `<div class="childWindow">`).

Comment: validate your html and remove your div or replace with an inline tag as a span. inline tags can be styled as block via CSS if needed. `span {display:block;}` is valid and has nothing to do with semantics.

Comment: thanks guys.. issue is solved, sorry for idiotic questions, i am new to html coding

Comment: @oh_dear_i_love_coding looks like you've not quite realized what's wrong in your HTML code, or maybe you don't really know why the HTML code is invalid. Here is an example: `<span><div></div></span>` -> this is a valid HTML code and this `<span><div></span></div>` is not valid at all. That's exactly your case.

Answer (score 1):

The label tag is used to tie other elements to a form element. Remove the text from the label tag for it to not trigger checkbox checkage.

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked/>
    <span>This will trigger checkboxage</span>
</label>
<span>This won't trigger checkboxage</span>
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/casTu/

Comment: Your updated code isn't valid, your div tag isn't nested correctly.

Comment: @sicks it's not his updated code. I've just edited to align the code ***without any change***.